# Issue with existing system Python and installing Anaconda for a new Python - new to programming

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

As someone who is just getting started with programming and installing Python, I am looking for an answer to an installation question that hopefully doesn't involve much coding itself. This is the bottleneck that is keeping me from utilizing Python and downloading spyder, pandas etc. that I need to learn for work.

In trying to install Anaconda on my Windows PC, I am getting an error 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZuqp.png). Basically, it says that if I want Anaconda registered as my system Python, that I unregister this earlier Python first. This earlier Python was installed as a default part of the Pymol program installation package, which I use for structural analysis.

Based on reading the one question that has asked this on stack exchange in the past, it sounds like this means that python has already been integrated on my Windows and now when I try to code, the system will need to figure out whether I would like to do so in the Anaconda environment or with the non-anaconda Python. My questions are a) how do I unregister this other python? b) should I just uninstall the whole Pymol program (and with it, the python)? c) If I say "ok" to this prompt and download Anaconda, will this cause problems with my existing Python installation or will it not matter in the end?

I also tried emailing Anaconda support a few times before realizing that they don't provide individual support unless you're an enterprise user.

Would appreciate any and all advice on this issue so I can move forward. Thanks very much.

Comment: _My questions are a) how do I unregister this other python?_ If I'm understanding that prompt correctly, all you need to do is click "OK". The [Anaconda FAQ](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/faq/#installing-anaconda) says that existing Python installations are not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unregister your previous PYTHON installation. Edit your SYSTEM PATH should fix this. In case your anaconda is before your *other* python installation, or remove your *older* Python for it at all. How to set your PATH ?, check [hier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages):